# Sum (case when column name then 1 else 0) always returns one row. How can I make it not return nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN alert_header = 'Overspeeding' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS overspeeding,
    SUM(CASE WHEN alert_header = 'Tyre Pressure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tyre_pressure,
    itms_assets.assets_name,
    fname,
    lname
FROM itms_alert_master
LEFT JOIN itms_assets
    ON (itms_assets.asset_id = itms_alert_master.asset_id)
LEFT JOIN itms_personnel_master
    ON (itms_personnel_master.personnel_id = itms_alert_master.driver_id)
WHERE
    itms_alert_master.del_date IS NULL
    AND itms_alert_master.company_id = '" . $company_id . "'
```

Comment: Try removing the `ELSE` part.

Comment: I cannot replicate the reported behaviour

Comment: You don't have a group by.

Comment: @fancyPants Yes, but I assumed you would have several fname/lname/itms_assets.assets_name so you should group by them.

Comment: @Pholochtairze I didn't read the question properly. Sorry, you're right.

Comment: basically I am getting a blank assoc array with only keys.

Comment: @FelixPamittan That did not work

Comment: I solved the problem by having a count(*) as data_size in query, and checking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by having a "count(*) as data_size" in query, and checking that if it is "0".